# How to Redirect a URL to another URL if user is not Logged in: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have a directory out side the app folder as this localhost/myproject/director
i want to made a redirection for this directory. if someone is not logged in and direct access this directory so it will be redirected to home page.

```
i have tried this but nothing works:
if(!$_SESSION['login']){
header("location:index.php");
die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Session is set like this

```
$newdata = array(
   'username'  => 'johndoe',
   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
   'logged_in' => TRUE
);
```

So to check

```
if(logged_in == TRUE)
{
    # logged User
    $this->load->view("homepage");
}
else{
    #not logged User
    redirect("Login"); # set login controller name
}
```

---

**For Your Information**

If User Log once then set session with your input data

```
$newdata = array(
   'username'  => $user_name,
   'email'     => $email,
   'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

---

[Codeigniter Session Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)